# CSS Layout CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple page (Only using HTML and CSS) but I am having a difficulty with some elements: I have attached links here what I want to achieve and what I have done.

Question is:

1.  How can I put the pink background overlap all the text and images?

- I tried to do this in CSS:

  `#setBackground {

  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index:-1;

  }`
- And in HTML:

  `<div id="setBackground">

  <img src="/images/pinkbg.png" alt="Background"/>
  </div>`
- But still didnt work.

I know it is not fancy but if you anyone could give me some suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Making several questions in a single post makes it a lot harder for this to become a useful resource for others in the future. Each entry in Stack Overflow is supposed to be ONE question.

Comment: Too many question .. one by one please ...

Comment: @matzone Okay, I have edited the question and removed all and left only one question. http://jsfiddle.net/5GRpH/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pink does not overlap but is `underneath` so that when you place transparent things on top of it, you can see the pink underneath. In this case to set the pink color would require a

```
 background-color: rgb(245,195,195);
```

Here is an example of how to layout the background: http://jsfiddle.net/EAHQw/6/

All of the additional content would go inside those two div's and would thus be placed on top giving them the desired pink background.

I went and made a more complete example. http://jsfiddle.net/GEwYJ/2/

You'll see I cheated for the circles, but you could easily make that image in an image editing program that supports 3d rotation. You could probably do it with pure css, but I am not good enough with transformations for that and it would probably be simpler to do it with just an image. Also I made it smaller so that it would fit inside the box better. It isn't a perfect copy, but it could pass as a close approximation.

Also I used a mixture of class names ID's and psudo selectors to show different ways to apply styles. In a production environment it would be better to have a more consistent structure.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion - But can you tell me how you managed to get the RGB in that format? ie; If I want to get white or other colors where can I get those numbers? Thanks.

Comment: thanks again, I have tried different color as you suggest yes it does work - but the problem I can't put the 'background pink' in the center. I tried to use:  
    background-position:center; but it didn't work?

Comment: I mean the 'pink background' should be in the middle. Let's say ie: when we look on the screen the full size of the screen in 100%, then we want to put the 'pink background' in a middle but not full maybe just 60% of the full screen and the top got say 5% white space background, right has 20%, bottom 5% and left has 20%. Sorry if my explanation isn't clear. I have tried to edit it as here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sm7KP/1/ -- but I cant seem put the text on top of the pink background?

Comment: @tagalo I updated my answer with a more complete example, let me know if that helps resolve some of your questions.

Comment: I have sorted it out thanks - I used margin-left to move the pink background around! It seems work - but I am having problem placing the text on top of the pink background.... - BTW it seems that the border-bottom-right-radius and box-shadow aren't support for some browsers? Any ideas what is the replacement if needed?

PS: I just seen your msg - I will update once I look it - thanks.

Comment: @tagalo Both `border-bottom-right-radius` and `box-shadow` are supported by IE9+, Firefox 4, Chrome, Opera, and Safari 5.1.1. Do you plan on designing this for older browsers?

Comment: No I am not intended to designing into older browsers but I know these elements did not support older browsers - but I will find out an alternative in case i need it thanks - I have run your latest code but it seems nothing change there? And I still not able to place my text on top of the 'pinky background'?

Comment: @tagalo Did you click the right link? http://jsfiddle.net/GEwYJ/2/

Comment: I noticed you using ` border-bottom-right-radius: 2pc` instead of `2em`? - is that the same function?

Comment: @tagalo It is just another unit of measurement, I really shouldn't use it but I wanted a nice round curve without trying multiple `px` values. `pc` is short for `pica`

Comment: oh yes now I can see the different - thanks I use the old version of your link that's why isn't the same! That looks great indeed! Just few questions though - as for the yellow "circle" the one on right top and the red sign errors - can it be done in CSS?

Comment: @tagalo They can be done in css, I just have no experience in drawing things with css transforms. It would probably be easier to use images instead.

Comment: I see thank you very much! You have been very helpful I shall review and revise the code. If I have any confusion I hope I can contact you only if that is okay with you? Again, thanks really appreciated it!

Comment: I was wondering if in case i want to change the page (ie;- bullets points) and able to extend vertically (without need to edit / add additional code etc) - what keyword/elements I should use? Is it the float?

Comment: @tagalo The float is just positioning, extending vertically would be a mix of changing heights and margins so that everything is spaced how you want it

Comment: hmmmm so if I want to add/edit it at later date - would it be better to use fluid layout? Is that what it means 'extending vertically'?

Comment: I just noticed this page won't work and display as it should be in IE, Safari and Chrome. In particular the arrow bits.

Answer (score 0):

1. with an z-index syntax in your css file
2. that is an image. or you can try it with css3...([www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com))
3. create a div box named 'box' or something like that and in your css file:

   ```
    #box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    }
   ```

4.

```
position: absolute;
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
top: 200px;
left: 50px;
background-color: black; (example... works with % instead of px, too)
```

5.

```
margin: right; (CSS works only if your text is in a div-box)
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks I tried to do an error as you suggested on #3 but that didn't work. And as for the #2 it is not an image it is CSS I believe we can create that rounded pattern in CSS? As for the #1, do I need to create a background first or just put z-index in CSS?